# YYYY-MM-DD format date in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, date, date-formatting, strftime

I tried using `$(date)` in my bash shell script, however, I want the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
How do I get this?

Comment: Comments must be at the least 15 words in length. date -I

Comment: Indeed `date -I` is all you need. It took me years to stumble upon that.

Comment: `date -I` only works on Linux using GNU tools, not on macOS / BSD; installing [brew](https://brew.sh) --> `brew install coreutils` makes `gdate -I` available

Comment: `date -r <TIMESTAMP> -I` works fine under the BSD tools FWIW.

Answer (score 2302, accepted):

In bash (>=4.2) it is preferable to use printf's built-in date formatter (part of bash) rather than the external `date` (usually GNU date). Note that invoking a subshell has performance problems in Cygwin due to a slow `fork()` call on Windows.

As such:

```
# put current date as yyyy-mm-dd in $date
# -1 -> explicit current date, bash >=4.3 defaults to current time if not provided
# -2 -> start time for shell
printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1 

# put current date as yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS in $date
printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n' -1 

# to print directly remove -v flag, as such:
printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1
# -> current date printed to terminal
```

In bash (<4.2):

```
# put current date as yyyy-mm-dd in $date
date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')

# put current date as yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS in $date
date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# print current date directly
echo $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
```

Other available date formats can be viewed from the [date man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) (for external non-bash specific command):

```
man date
```

Comment: In the first days of the month I get "2012-07-1" which is not what the OP asks for.

Comment: DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y" "%H:%M:%S); What I ended up after.

Comment: I haven't checked how widely available these shortcuts are, but in some distributions you can use `+%F %T` as a shortcut for `+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. Just note that _some filesystems_ (cough**HFS) will convert the `:` to a `/`, giving you a string like `2016-09-15 11/05/00` which is mighty confusing.

Comment: The preferred syntax in any POSIX-compliant shell in this millennium is `date=$(date)` instead of `date=\`date\``. Also, don't use uppercase for your private variables; uppercase variable names are reserved for the system.

Comment: The command to use is not a feature of Bash.  On OSX, the default shell is still Bash, but the `date` command accepts different options than on GNU (though this simple command should work on both).

Comment: If you want a two digit year use `%y` (lowercase) instead of `%Y` (uppercase)

Comment: How do I get the date without leading zeros? Current code returns 2017.02.06

Comment: On debian @beporter solution didn't work. It worked like this: date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" Extra \s between date and time gave the error.

Comment: `man date` does not explain the `+` which indicates the beginning of the format string.

Comment: @Timo My guess is that the `+` is to distinguish the format string from the `-` that indicates options

Comment: @harsh_v Surely the beauty of the YYYY-MM-DD date format is that it allows sorting dates easily.  Removing leading zeros would prevent that.

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533661/todays-date-minus-x-days-in-shell-script

Comment: `printf` can not format milliseconds. GNU `date` can.

Comment: `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S` is what I was looking for, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149753/48973 helped me realize that I needed to avoid spaces.

Comment: GNU `date` has simpler syntax than `printf`, which is why I prefer `date`.

Comment: Also if you want to get GMT / Universal time you can run date with additional "-u" flag: date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S -u

Comment: `echo $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')` can be replaced with `date '+%Y-%m-%d'` directly

Comment: I couldnt find way for printf to adjust date like this `date=$(date '+%Y%m%d' -d "60 days ago")` so I wouldnt say you should always use it even with newer bash.

Answer (score 525):

Try: `$(date +%F)`

The `%F` option is an alias for `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: The man pages for date reads: %F full date; same as %Y-%m-%d, so this is just a more compact notation for the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer works in `zsh` as well.

Answer (score 163):

You can do something like this:

```
$ date +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: By far the easiest to remember and most configurable method... less is more!

Answer (score 93):

```
$(date +%F)
```

output

```
2018-06-20
```

Or if you also want time:

```
$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)
```

can be used to remove colons (:) in between

output

```
2018-06-20_09-55-58
```

Comment: Appreciate the addtional time - OP may not have asked, but I'm sure most people googling this are interested!

Comment: `%T` is an useful alias for `%H:%M:%S`, too.

Comment: Thanks also @mgutt! I went for `$(date '+%F_%T')` in the end.

Answer (score 58):

You're looking for [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format, so if you have GNU date (or any date command more modern than 1988) just do: `$(date -I)`

Comment: I have a recent (>1988) Mac OS X computer, and `date -I` didn't work. Having installed [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils) using [brew](http://brew.sh/) (which uses the prefix 'g') `gdate -I` did work.

Comment: Odd. I can't find the `-I` option documented for GNU `date`, although sure enough it does seem to be equivalent to `date +%F`.

Comment: OS X is generally a GPL v3 wasteland, so they might just not have updated date or BASH recently.

Comment: I like this option because it doesn't require escaping `%` in cron.

Answer (score 27):

```
date -d '1 hour ago' '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

The output would be `2015-06-14`.

Comment: Wrong for a couple of reasons, obviously this gives the wrong date between 00:00 and 01:00, and besides you end with a `%`.

Comment: it's not true. should be like this  sparse single quote

Answer (score 24):

With recent Bash (version ≥ 4.2), you can use the builtin `printf` with the format modifier `%(strftime_format)T`:

```
$ printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1  # Get YYYY-MM-DD (-1 stands for "current time")
2017-11-10
$ printf '%(%F)T\n' -1  # Synonym of the above
2017-11-10
$ printf -v date '%(%F)T' -1  # Capture as var $date
```

`printf` is much faster than `date` since it's a Bash builtin while `date` is an external command.

As well, `printf -v date ...` is faster than `date=$(printf ...)` since it doesn't require forking a subshell.

Comment: As a note in 2019, this command is incredibly faster* than `date` if you are using this from within a bash script already, as it doesn't have to load any extra libraries. (* I measured on my linux server a ~160x speed difference over 1000 iterations)

Comment: @timtj Thanks for pointing that out! I added some notes about speed to the answer.

Comment: I wish I could +5 for the comment about `printf -v date` not forking a subshell. Very good info!!

Comment: Usually I use date because I also need to increment through some dates. Can printf do date arithmetic?

Comment: @Merlin I don't think so

Answer (score 21):

I use the following formulation:

```
TODAY=`date -I`
echo $TODAY
```

Checkout the man page for `date`, there is a number of other useful options:

```
man date
```

Comment: This answer seems equivalent to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195700/9164010), which actually uses the other syntax `$( … )` for command substitution; see e.g. [GreyCat](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/)'s [BashFAQ #082](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for details.

Answer (score 13):

if you want the year in a two number format such as 17 rather than 2017, do the following:

```
DATE=`date +%d-%m-%y`
```

Answer (score 11):

I used below method. Thanks for all methods/answers

```
ubuntu@apj:/tmp$ datevar=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d : %H-%M')
ubuntu@apj:/tmp$ echo $datevar
2022-03-31 : 10-48
```

Answer (score 9):

Whenever I have a task like this I end up falling back to

```
$ man strftime
```

to remind myself of all the possibilities for time formatting options.

Answer (score 9):

I use `$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")`  or `$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")` with time and hours.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this command :

```
date | cut -d " " -f2-4 | tr " " "-"
```

The output would be like: `21-Feb-2021`

Comment: this is the worst method ever! Not only it's longer and slower, it also **doesn't work at all for most locales**. Try `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 date`, `LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 date`, `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 date`, `LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 date`, or `LC_ALL=el_GR.UTF-8 date`... for example. It doesn't even work for all English locales

Comment: `date` outputs a human-readable date in the current locale, so parsing it is as useless as parsing `apt install` output

Answer (score 7):

`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`

will print something like 2023-07-18T11:09:16 which is generally known as RFC-3339

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

x='2018-01-18 10:00:00'
a=$(date -d "$x")
b=$(date -d "$a 10 min" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
c=$(date -d "$b 10 min" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#date -d "$a 30 min" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

echo Entered Date is $x
echo Second Date is $b
echo Third Date is $c
```

Here x is sample date used & then example displays both formatting of data as well as getting dates 10 mins more then current date.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "`date "+%F"`"
```

Will print YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: 1) There were already so many answers on `%F`. 2) This is wrong & redundant in so many levels: using backticks is deprecated, see the unreadable quotes? using `$()` would be much more readable; there's no need to spawn a subshell, capture its output and print with `echo` when a single `date "+%F"` in the current shell is already enough

Answer (score 0):

You can set date as environment variable and later u can use it

```
setenv DATE `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
echo "----------- ${DATE} -------------"
```

or

```
DATE =`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
echo "----------- ${DATE} -------------"
```

Comment: ```backticks`` ``` are obsolete and deprecated long ago. Never use them, use `$()` instead which is nestable and readable

Answer (score -5):

Try this code for a simple human readable timestamp:

```
dt=$(date)
echo $dt
```

Output:

```
Tue May 3 08:48:47 IST 2022
```

Comment: the OP asked specifically for the YYYY-MM-DD format