# Today's date, minus X days in shell script

Tags: bash, sh

I need to create three variables, each for Year, Month, and Day for Today's date, minus X number of days.  For this question I'll choose a random amount of days: 222.

So if:

```
TodayYear=`date +%Y`
TodayMonth=`date +%m`
TodayDay=`date +%d`
```

What I want is 222 days before this.

```
222days_before_TodayYear=???
222days_before_TodayMonth=???
222days_before_TodayDay=???
```

Edit: Need 222 **working** days instead 222 regular days.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**For GNU `date`:**

```
date_222days_before_TodayYear=$(date --date="222 days ago" +"%Y")
date_222days_before_TodayMonth=$(date --date="222 days ago" +"%m")
date_222days_before_TodayDay=$(date --date="222 days ago" +"%d")
```

---

**For BSD `date`:**:

If you are using OS X or FreeBSD, use the following instead because BSD date is different from GNU date:

```
date_222days_before_TodayYear=$(date -j -v-222d +"%Y")
date_222days_before_TodayMonth=$(date -j -v-222d +"%m")
date_222days_before_TodayDay=$(date -j -v-222d +"%d")
```

Source: [BSD date manual page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/date/)

**Note:**

In `bash` and many other languages, you cannot start a variable name with a numerical character, so I prefixed them with `date_` for you.

---

**Second Update:** New requirement - *Using 222 Working days instead of 222 Regular days:*

(**Assumption:** Not considering statutory holidays, because that just gets far beyond the scope of what I can help you with in a shell script:)

Consider 222 working days:

- 5 working days per week, that is `floor(222/5) == 44 weeks`
- `44 weeks * 7 days per week == 308 days`
- Extra days leftover: `222 % 5 == 2`
- Therefore `222 working days == 310 regular days`

But, there is a catch! If the number of regular days is `308` or some multiple of `7`, then we would have been fine, because any multiple of 7-days ago from a working day is still a working day. So we need to consider whether today is a Monday or a Tuesday:

- If today is a Monday, we'd get Saturday where we wanted Thursday
- If today is a Tuesday, we'd get Sunday where we wanted Friday

So you see we need an additional offset of 2 more days if today is either Monday or Tuesday; so let's find that out first before we proceed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use 310 days as offset instead of 222
offset=310
# Find locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Sun)
today=$(date -j +"%a")
# Check for Mon/Tue
if [[ "$today" == "Mon" ]] || [[ "$today" == "Tue" ]]; then
     offset=$((offset+2))
fi

date_222_working_days_before_TodayYear=$(date -j -v-${offset}d +"%Y")
date_222_working_days_before_TodayMonth=$(date -j -v-${offset}d +"%m")
date_222_working_days_before_TodayDay=$(date -j -v-${offset}d +"%d")
```

And that should do it =)

Comment: I get `date: illegal date format` - I wonder if I might be using the wrong type of quotation marks (I copied and pasted from here but that script errored).  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1644609 try the updated answer, but the quotes before shouldn't be the error. Your question is tagged `bash`, but do you know which version of shell you are using?

Comment: Thanks @sampson-chen - I've tried your update, but now, instead of getting `illegal date format` I get `illegal time format` (and then usage instructions).  My bash version is: `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: @user1644609: edited my answer - try the latest revision this *should* work

Comment: Get this error now: `date: illegal option -- -` (and then usage instructions)

Comment: @user1644609: is that from entering **just** `date --date="222 days ago" +"%Y"` on your terminal prompt?

Comment: @sampson-chen initially no, I was doing this in a script, but when I copied and pasted your last comment at the terminal prompt, I got illegal option again

Comment: @user1644609: see updated answer if you are using OS X - did a bit of digging and I think that's the correct syntax for `darwin` (Using `-j -v-222d` to specify that you aren't setting system time, and you want to adjust to minus 222 days ago.)

Comment: @sampson-chen - I still can't get it to work.  The usage instructions I'm getting in Darwin are:  `usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
`

Comment: @user1644609 did you try it with `-j -v-222d` as in the latest revision?

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting as you were updating.  Latest version works!  Can I ask if I were to switch to Ubuntu/Fedora (which I plan to next year), your first version will work?

Comment: @user1644609 Huzzah, it works! :D - and yes, that is correct, as I believe both Ubuntu and Fedora are GNU.

Comment: @sampson-chen - just realized my actual needs are different than my question :(  I don't need 222 days before.... I need 222 WORKING days before (American working days).... ouch!  I'm guessing there is no easy way to do that one!

Comment: @user1644609 I thought about it for a bit and it's more feasible than you'd think with help of some inferences; check updated answer =)

Comment: @sampson-chen Wow, thanks a lot.  That is awesome.  I didn't expect that so I was working on a workaround.  In both cases (working days, or regular days), I need to represent January as 0, February as 1 (or 01), March as 2 (or 02), etc... I tried this: `MONTHS200=$(date -j -v-320d -v-1m +"%m")
if ${MONTHS200}=01; then
 ${MONTH200}=0
else
 ${MONTHS200}=${MONTH200}
fi
` But I get the error `./update_newdateformat.sh: line 20: 12=01: command not found
./update_newdateformat.sh: line 23: 12=: command not found`  The `-v-1m` works for all months except January, because it goes to 12, instead of 0

Comment: @user1644609 I would start a separate question on StackOverflow because you are now describing problems with the variable assignment / comparison syntax. Just point me to it when you have it up.

Comment: @sampson-chen Thanks Sampson, its over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535871/changing-variable-on-set-of-conditions

Answer (score 7):

```
date '+%Y' --date='222 days ago'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get exact past date from the following in bash

```
Number=222
current_date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
past_date=$(date -d "$current_date - $Number days" +%Y%m%d)
echo "$current_date\t$past_date"
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 3):

```
epoch=$(( `date '+%s'` - ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 222 ) ))
year=`date -d "@$epoch" '+%Y'`
month=`date -d "@$epoch" '+%m'`
day=`date -d "@$epoch" '+%d'`
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: When I do this, the console doesn't return any errors, but it just says: `usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Answer (score 0):

I would say easier solution would be

```
222days_before_TodayYear = $(date -v -222d +%Y)
222days_before_TodayMonth = $(date -v -222d +%m)
222days_before_TodayDay = $(date -v -222d +%d)
```