# Changing variable on set of conditions

Tags: macos, bash

This question is related to the thread here:

[Today's date, minus X days in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533661/todays-date-minus-x-days-in-shell-script#13533753)

But because I'm now manipulating the variable, I started another thread.

As described above, I need to get today's date minus 200 days, with the Year, Month, and Day in separate variables (in this question I'll use 200, though in the other it's 222).  However, I need to represent January as 0, February as 1 (or 01), March as 2 (or 02), etc... I tried this:

```
MONTHS200=$(date -j -v-200d -v-1m +"%m")
if ${MONTHS200}=01; then 
${MONTH200}=0
else ${MONTHS200}=${MONTH200}
fi
```

But I get the error `./update_newdateformat.sh: line 20: 12=01: command not found ./update_newdateformat.sh: line 23: 12=: command not found` The `-v-1m` works for all months except January, because it goes to 12, instead of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to shift all the month number down by 1 n your script:

```
MONTHS200=$(date -j -v-320d +"%m")

# Remove leading zero if there is one, so it doesn't cause problems later
MONTHS200=${MONTHS200#0}

MONTHS200=$((MONTHS200-1))
```

Here is how to use `if` and `=` (assignment) syntax in shell:

```
if [[ "${MONTHS200}" == "01" ]]; then
    MONTHS200="0"
else
    MONTHS200=${AnotherVariable}
fi
```

Note that for numerical comparisons, you need to use:

- `-eq` instead of `==`
- `-ne` instead of `!=`
- `-lt` instead of `<`
- `-le` instead of `<=`
- `-gt` instead of `>`
- `-ge` instead of `>=`

For example:

```
 if [[ "${MONTHS200}" -eq 1 ]]; then
```

Comment: should that -v-1m be in that first line?

Comment: You're earlier solution (with a minor edit) worked: `MONTH200=$(date -j -v-320d +"%m")
MONTH200=$((MONTH200-1))`

Comment: @user1644609 just edited again, see updated answer and explanations =)

Answer (score 1):

I would take advantage of bash features (I assume OSX bash is recent enough -- I might be wrong). You only need to call `date` once with

```
read year month day < <(date -j -v-200d +"%Y %m %d")
month=$(( 10#$month - 1 ))
```

You avoid the octal issue by forcing bash to use base-10