# Set date function as variable and use in beeline and hql file (hive)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

Could anyone please explain to me how to solve this issue.

I want to use from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - 86400, 'yyyyMMdd) as the value for a variable and use it in a query's where clause that is stored in an hql file. I have tried:

beeline --hiveconf date=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyyMMdd) -f path/file.hql (in .hql file: WHERE date <= '${hiveconf:date}';)

It does not work because of the date function. Is there any way to first get the date value in some script and then use it together with the hql file? I have only seen examples with hive cli but not beeline and I have tried some different ways but can't get it to work. Would really appreciate some help. The query works with hardcoded dates.

Thanks!

Comment: instead of using the hive udfs for generating the date , use the unix date functions so as to generate the date value for the hive variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the unix date functions you could convert the date to the required format and then pass to the hive variable. Below is a sample command you could use :

```
cur_date=`date +%Y%m%d`
beeline --hiveconf date=${cur_date} -f path/file.hql
```

Then in your hive query just use ${date} where ever required.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! How can I subtract 30 days from that date format? I'm using terminal on mac some of the commands I find on google does not seem to work :)

Comment: you could refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533661/todays-date-minus-x-days-in-shell-script

Comment: Ok thanks but the code is not working the query does not seem to take the variable value some how :(

Comment: Which one ? The one which I have mentioned ? I have just tried the following command and it worked ; today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
hive -hivevar client_date=${today} -f query.hql > ${today}.tsv

Comment: I got it to work when I set the variable directly to the function( beeline --hiveconf date= date +%Y-%m-%d.

I had an issue with my query the LIMIT 10; did not work but I can live with that for now. Now I have to figure out how to subtract 30 days, If you do have a direct answer please let me know :)