# grep current date to 7 days back without specific date

Tags: linux, grep

In my log a date is saved in the form of `May 01 11:01:30 2018`. In `grep` I can not give specific dates such as `grep "May 0[1-8]"`.

How can I do a `grep` or other search command which searches the log 7 days back from the current date?

Example: Current date - 7 days back

If it is possible? Or simple script?

Best regards!

Comment: might be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533661/todays-date-minus-x-days-in-shell-script#13533706

Answer (score 0):

Depending on further goals you try to achieve, type of logs and complexity, it might be necessary to write a small script. Have a look in example into [How to get all the log lines between two dates ranges in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441578/how-to-get-all-the-log-lines-between-two-dates-ranges-in-linux).

---

<sub>*For quick reference I'll provide my answer here too ...*</sub>

An approach I am using frequently for log files from Java applications is to find the line number of the first occurrence of the time stamps

```bash
FROM_DATE="Wed 21 Mar 14:52:08"
TO_DATE=""Wed 21 Mar 14:53:08"

FROM_LINE=$(grep -n -m 1 ${FROM_DATE} ${FILE} | cut -d ":" -f 1)
TO_LINE=$(grep -n -m 1 ${TO_DATE} ${FILE} | cut -d ":" -f 1)
```

then give out the information between, i.e.

```bash
tail -n "${FROM_LINE}" ${FILE} | head -n $(expr $TO_LINE - $FROM_LINE)
```

or via

```bash
sed -n -e "${FROM_LINE},${TO_LINE} p" -e "${TO_LINE} q" ${FILE}
```

This will catch up stack traces, REST API content, JSON structures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this: `grep -A 100000 "$(date +'%b %d' -d '-7 days')" myservice.log`

Where you could insert something larger than `1000000` if you need more lines.

The date command argument `+'%b %d'` gives you the format you want and the argument `-d '-7 days'` gives you the date from 7 days ago. `grep -A` then gives you the first match and `100000` lines after the last match on your file.

Comment: Good catch @exic. Might not be feasible for some of my logs of the Hadoop framework, but for a lot of others.