# Passing a date to a ruby function as STDIN in BASH

Tags: ruby, bash, date

I have a ruby file that I would normally run in command line as follows:

```
ruby file.rb YYYY-MM-DD YYYY_MM_DD
```

I want to write a bash script to run this file where both `YYYY-MM-DD` are strings for yesterday's date.

How would I do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with STDIN? Command line arguments are not STDIN.

Answer (score 3):

```
ruby file.rb $(date -d yesterday +'%Y-%m-%d') $(date -d yesterday +'%Y_%m_%d')
```

Note that this will only work in bash. Other Bourne-like shells will work if you use backticks instead of `$()`.

Comment: The caveat is wrong; `$(command)` should work in any POSIX shell. If you're on something truly ancient like SunOS 3, then maybe.

Answer (score 2):

See "[YYYY-MM-DD format date in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401482/yyyy-mm-dd-format-date-in-shell-script)" to figure out how to get the date in whatever format you want.

Yesterday's date can be found as:

```
date -d '1 day ago' +'%Y/%m/%d'
```

from "[How To Get Yesterday’s Date using BASH Shell Scripting](http://www.masaokitamura.com/2009/02/17/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-using-bash-shell-scripting/)".

Replace the `/` with `-` or `_` and then pass them in to the Ruby statement.

Edit: Vote for the other guy. Their answer actually has code.