# How do I write a regex to match and capture at the same time?

Tags: ruby

I have a pseudo-code method that works like this:

```
def my_method(file)
  while(line = file.gets)
    case line
      when /^TEXT (.*)/
        puts line + <the text captured in the parenthesis of the regex> 
      else
        .....
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:

The sample string is like:

```
TEXT a sample text
```

I want to have "a sample text" captured by the regex. I know this is not the proper way to do this, but this is just a demonstration, i.e. "[YYYY-MM-DD format date in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401482/yyyy-mm-dd-format-date-in-shell-script)" to figure out how to get the date in whatever format you want.

Yesterday's date can be found as:

```
date -d '1 day ago' +'%Y/%m/%d'
```

from "[How To Get Yesterday’s Date using BASH Shell Scripting](http://www.masaokitamura.com/2009/02/17/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-using-bash-shell-scripting/)".

Replace the `/` with `-` or `_` and then pass them in to the Ruby statement.

Edit: Vote for the other guy. Their answer actually has code.

Comment: give us the sample strings...otherwise how would we understand ?

Comment: it is just a string "TEXT"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `puts "line#{$1}"`. The pseudo-globals `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. refer to capture groups of the last Regexp match. (And `$~` refers to the MatchData itself, if you'd like to work with that.)