# Pentaho data integration logging backup

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I wanted to have Kettle logging backup per day. By default Kettle writes its log into standard output. I'm able to write logging into files and also sets the logging level. But it'll write to a single file only. I'm using Pentaho data integration stable release 4.2.0

Is there a way to backup last days log? (Like using log4j in Java)

Comment: PDI uses log4j. See if this [thread](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?81269-PDI-logging-via-Log4J) helps.

Comment: Brian, I checked the link. But I didn't find any way to backup log files daily basis. In log4j, we can use DailyRollingAppender. And by mentioning DatePattern we can backup our daily old logs. Can you please suggest how can I achieve those properties?

Answer (score 1):

There is ability to store job/transformation log to the specified database table.
Go to transformation/job properties -> logging tab. 
You can specify file based db connection (Hypersonic and etc).
It would be the simplest decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing in a *NIX environment you could just redirect standard out/standard error to a log file name containing a date. Example below.

```
"Job Execute Command" 2>> JobLog_`date +%Y-%m-%d`.log
```

*[YYYY-MM-DD format date in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401482/yyyy-mm-dd-format-date-in-shell-script)

Comment: Yaa, That I can do anyway. But I wanted the backup log files configured through kettle only. PDI internally uses log4j for logging purpose.