# Having issues moving files and creating year month day folders

Tags: linux, bash

When I backup my files I want to create a Year, Month & Date folder to place the files into. I am just learning coding for linux so I apologies. This is what I have currently:

```
#!/bin/ash
chmod +x FTP.sh
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:$PATH
SOURCE=/volume1/DOCS/documents/C59/tiffs
MKDIR=/documents/C59/$(date)
```

I am using a Synology NAS. I added the Date code but its giving me the following folder path:

/documents/C59/Tue/tiffs

Comment: Hello. Maybe you can use the **date** command to extract the time information and create a folder (dd_mm_yy).

`mkdir $(date +"%D" | sed "s/\//_/g")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YYYY-MM-DD format date in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401482/yyyy-mm-dd-format-date-in-shell-script)

Comment: Sorry @sashoalm that didn't answer my question. I am getting Tue to appear in my folder path not Year/Month/Day

Answer (score 0):

In the bash script, use:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

To create a folder, you can use:

```
mkdir yourFolderName
```

PS: search before asking a question, this has been answered many times already ;)

[YYYY-MM-DD format date in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401482/yyyy-mm-dd-format-date-in-shell-script)

Comment: Thank you very much. Where would I place that though within the code. Sorry im very noobish with this. I am trying to learn :) thanks again.

Comment: Ok so when I place this code into my file this is what I get:
documents/C59/Tue/tiffs